# Django Model Form Validation & Integrity Error

Tags: python, django, forms, validation

I'm trying to use the ModelForm in Django 1.7, with a model that looks like that:

```
class Record(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(default='')
    ean = models.BigIntegerField(
        unique=True,
        blank=False,
        verbose_name='EAN Code or any code that could identify the Item',
    )
    year = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=2000)
    artist = models.ForeignKey(
        'Artist',
        blank=False,
        related_name='records',
        )
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('id',)
        unique_together = ('artist','name')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('view_record',args=[self.id])
```

And a form that looks like that :

```
class RecordForm(forms.models.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Record
        fields = ('name','year','artist','ean')
        widgets= {
            'name': forms.fields.TextInput(attrs={
            'placeholder': 'Name of the Record',
            'class': "form-control input-lg",
            }),
        }
        error_messages = {
            'name': {'required':EMPTY_ITEM_ERROR},
            'ean': {'required':EMPTY_ITEM_ERROR}
        }
    def save(self):
        return super().save()
```

And I don't understand why the method validate() don't raise an error when the field "ean" is empty meanwhile the DB screems Integrity Errors :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.IntegrityError: null value in column "ean" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (28, record1, 27, null, 2000).
```

I'm new with Django and Python, But I would think that the field with "blank=False" would be enought to raise a validation error ?
Thank you for help

Comment: Why would you think that? If you want the db to accept null, you should declare the field as `null=False`.

Comment: Daniel, in the docs it says that it need the value True to accept null values, am I missing something?

Comment: I would think that because it's written here : [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.blank)

Comment: Please post your view function or class in order to see how you're handling the POSTed form and saving the result to the db. For example, you might not be calling form.is_valid() first or otherwise not triggering the validation process correctly.